# Using promises in sync operation because of chain

Tags: javascript, bluebird

i have this chain:

```
phase_one(files).then(phase_two).then(phase_three).then(phase_four);
```

Each phase will receive this array with object files inside. And inside each phases, i have this default piece of code:

```
  return Promise.map(files, function(file) {
    // some code here
  }, {
    concurrency: 3000
  });
```

The problem is.. phase_two is synchronous... but i want still use the chain i shouldn't use the Promise.map.

I would like to know if there is anything to help me with this in bluebird. I search in the docs and i didn't find.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`phase_two` can just be a function that returns a value.  The chain will continue just fine.

```
phase_one(files).then(phase_two).then(phase_three).then(phase_four);

function phase_two(input) {
    // do something
    return result;
}
```

A `.then()` handler can be either synchronous or asynchronous.  If it's asynchronous, then it must return a promise.  If it's synchronous, it can just return a value which become the value passed to the next part of the chain.

---

The very first link in the chain must return a promise (to start the chain).  If `phase_one()` is synchronous and you want to keep with the structure you had before, then you can just `return Promise.resolve(data);` from within `phase_one()`.  This will make the return value a promise which will have a `.then()` handler.

Comment: That's what i read a few minutes ago, but if i try just to return, will cause this error @jfriend00: Extraction.phase_two(...).then is not a function

Comment: @JoãoCalvin - Show your actual code.  Done properly, you can use synchronous code in a `.then()` handler and just return the value.  I do it all the time.

Comment: i was wrong, it's phase_one that i synchronous. Take a look http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOywWz?editors=101

Comment: This will throw: XXXtract.phase_one(...).then

Comment: @JoãoCalvin - see what I added to my answer.   You can `return Promise.resolve(xxx);` to start the chain with an initial promise.

Comment: yep! This works pretty well!! Thank you again @jfriend00

Comment: @JoãoCalvin - You can also do `Promise.resolve(files).then(phase_one).then(phase_two).then(...)`.

Comment: I think i prefer this option @jfriend00.